# Can a C# custom attribute specify the type of method it is applied to?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, compile-time

I know I can use `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]` to make sure a custom attribute can only be applied to a method, but can I go further and get a compile-time error if the custom attribute is applied to a method with a signature other than the one I specify?

For example, can I create an attribute that can only be attached to a method that returns `int` and takes a single `int` parameter?

Comment: If you have fixed signatures, maybe consider an interface instead of an attribute?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the suggestion. I've actually got a small set of possible signatures. It might still work, but I'd have to create several interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but can I go further and get a compile-time error if the custom
>   attribute is applied to a method with a signature other than the one I
>   specify?

No, you can't, this simply is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you've a workaround: .NET Framework supports attributes on methods' input parameters and return values.

```
[MyAttribute1]
[return: MyAttribute2]
public int Method([MyAttribute3] int some)
{
    return "";
}
```

And the code inspecting the method can do things if the method has `MyAttribute1`, `MyAttribute2` and `MyAttribute3`.

Depending on your needs, maybe this is too ugly, but I don't know your actual requirements!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an attribute during compilation using PostSharp. [This link demonstrates Automatically Adding DataContract and DataMember Attributes](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/fa546b6c-9107-4d5f-b921-b93ead7c42a7.htm)